# CSS List - align list elements perfectly into the width with an equal gap between them

Tags: html, css

Let's keep this simple and short, I've made 2 dummy examples of my problem.

I have a container `section` which is `600px` wide, this section will container list of products.

each product is a 100x100 block, and there is a `margin` of `62px` between each product.

The `ul` is set on `display: inline-block` so it won't go one under each other.

Now in the following pen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yujLf
You can see what I want to do, can you see how the first row of squares, touch the border of the container & then the next element goes under?

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/948991c58a4edd54cf149c78d7db50d4.png))</sub>

You can see how it's perfectly aligned for the width, as there's a perfect equal margin between each element.

***Now this solution is a problem, because now the second row will have extra margin on the left side:***

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/337100e784aac4785b1c53f54d7d84c3.png))</sub>

I do have a solution for that, simply by changing `margin-left` to `margin-right` and disable `margin-right` for `ul li:last-child`.

But if I do that, I will not be able to align the last element with the border, like I did with the first example, take a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdhrJ

As you see, I had to change the `margin` to `40px` instead of `62px` to make it 4 elements per row.

Is it possible to implement what I want with using `ul`?

Comment: Why can't you just change it to margin-right:21px; instead of margin-right:40px;? See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/goCpk

Comment: @Mastrianni Because according to my design, there should be only 4 blocks per row, and the last element **must** be at the end of the container.

Comment: You can use CSS3 to do that. :nth-child can have math added on to the end of it so that the css only effects every 4th child.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your container is fixed at 600px, then the following solution will work:

```
ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 62px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

What I've done is change `margin-left` to `margin-right` in both of the above selectors. I've also changed your second selector from `first-child` to `nth-child`, to select the 4th element and every 4th element after that.

**[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tLhsi)**

Comment: Can you explain what does *4n* means? Awesome solution!

Comment: @BenBeri `nth-child` is a mathematical pseudo selector that works similarly to `first-child`, except you can customize the math and the numbering. In addition to Mastrianni's link, look up `nth-child` on the Mozilla Developer Network (an indispensable tool). **tl;dr** `4n` essentially means "select element number 4" and `+4` means "and then select every 4th element after that".

Comment: @TylerH Oh nice, that's a very smart technique!

Comment: @BenBeri Note that `nth-child` isn't supported in IE8, but IE9+ do support it (just in case you have super legacy support as a requirement for your work).

Comment: @TylerH Who cares about IE8 in this case? :D Thanks!

Comment: @BenBeri unfortunately many companies have developed webapps that don't work in newer versions of IE. Legend has it that there are even some out there that still require IE6 or IE7.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this hack instead? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IgKtD

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align:justify;
  vertical-align:top;
  font-size:0.001px;
}

ul::after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
  background:blue;
}

ul li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px purple;
  margin:0 20px;
}

ul li:nth-child(4n), ul li:last-child {
  margin-right:0;
}

ul li:nth-child(4n-3) {
  margin-left:0;
}
```